# fourth rank tensor in 6x6 matrix

Tags: tensors

Is there a ***Command*** in Mathematica that **fourth rank tensor** can be represented as ***6 by 6 matrix***?

Comment: [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayReshape.html), e.g., `ArrayReshape[m, {6,6}]` (if  `Times@@TensorDimensions[m] ==36`)?

Comment: @kglr, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
aa = Array[a, {2, 2, 3, 3}];
TensorRank[aa]
```

> 4

```
aa // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(1,1,1,1) & a(1,1,1,2) & a(1,1,1,3) \\
>  a(1,1,2,1) & a(1,1,2,2) & a(1,1,2,3) \\
>  a(1,1,3,1) & a(1,1,3,2) & a(1,1,3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(1,2,1,1) & a(1,2,1,2) & a(1,2,1,3) \\
>  a(1,2,2,1) & a(1,2,2,2) & a(1,2,2,3) \\
>  a(1,2,3,1) & a(1,2,3,2) & a(1,2,3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(2,1,1,1) & a(2,1,1,2) & a(2,1,1,3) \\
>  a(2,1,2,1) & a(2,1,2,2) & a(2,1,2,3) \\
>  a(2,1,3,1) & a(2,1,3,2) & a(2,1,3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(2,2,1,1) & a(2,2,1,2) & a(2,2,1,3) \\
>  a(2,2,2,1) & a(2,2,2,2) & a(2,2,2,3) \\
>  a(2,2,3,1) & a(2,2,3,2) & a(2,2,3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
ArrayReshape[aa, {6, 6}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  a(1,1,1,1) & a(1,1,1,2) & a(1,1,1,3) & a(1,1,2,1) & a(1,1,2,2) & a(1,1,2,3) \\
>  a(1,1,3,1) & a(1,1,3,2) & a(1,1,3,3) & a(1,2,1,1) & a(1,2,1,2) & a(1,2,1,3) \\
>  a(1,2,2,1) & a(1,2,2,2) & a(1,2,2,3) & a(1,2,3,1) & a(1,2,3,2) & a(1,2,3,3) \\
>  a(2,1,1,1) & a(2,1,1,2) & a(2,1,1,3) & a(2,1,2,1) & a(2,1,2,2) & a(2,1,2,3) \\
>  a(2,1,3,1) & a(2,1,3,2) & a(2,1,3,3) & a(2,2,1,1) & a(2,2,1,2) & a(2,2,1,3) \\
>  a(2,2,2,1) & a(2,2,2,2) & a(2,2,2,3) & a(2,2,3,1) & a(2,2,3,2) & a(2,2,3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: very helpful for me!